# Как подсчитать сумму значений столбца в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
    name_cust, name_service, date_complite, cost_service,
    COUNT(name_service) AS count, 
    cost_service * COUNT(name_service) AS sums, 
    SUM(sums) as total
FROM 
    ordersComplite 
GROUP BY 
    name_cust, name_service;
```

Пишет в перечислении столбцов есть неизвестный sums. Как сделать его известным?)
Мне надо чтобы после подсчета произведения в sums, в столбце total высчитывалась сумма всего столбца sums. Как это можно сделать, не добавляя новых столбцов в таблицу?

Comment: Алиас выходного набора не может использоваться в выражении другого поля этого набора. *Мне надо чтобы после подсчета произведения в sums, в столбце total высчитывалась сумма всего столбца sums.* `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`. Либо `SUM(cost_service * COUNT(name_service)) OVER () as total` - если версия сервера позволяет.

Comment: А зачем дублировать total в каждой строке? Не очень осмысленный результат получается.

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы использовать вычисляемый столбец `sums` в запросе, необходимо повторить его определение в предложении `SELECT`, а затем использовать функцию `SUM()` для получения суммы значений этого столбца. В вашем случае предложение `SELECT` должно быть следующим:

```
SELECT name_cust, name_service, date_complite, cost_service, COUNT(name_service) AS count, cost_service * COUNT(name_service) AS sums, SUM(cost_service * COUNT(name_service)) as total
FROM ordersComplite GROUP BY name_cust, name_service;
```

Теперь столбец `sums` будет известен и вы можете использовать его вычисленные значения в столбце `total`, используя функцию `SUM()`. Обратите внимание, что название столбца `sums` теперь распознается благодаря его определению в начале запроса.

Comment: *`SUM(cost_service * COUNT(name_service)) as total`* Вложенные агрегатные функции недопустимы.